# react-hot-loader not working with webpack v1

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I had this configuration before

```
 module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loaders:['react-hot','babel-loader'],
        query: {presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]},
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
};
```

to add hot-loader, I had to change 'loader' to 'loaders' but then got a problem with webpack not able to read query. to fixed, I tried this but didn't work

var webpack = require('webpack');

```
module.exports = {
  entry:
  [
     'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000', // WebpackDevServer host and port
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // "only" prevents reload on syntax errors
  './scripts/index',   

  "script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "script!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js",
  "./app/app.jsx"
  ],
  externals: {
jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
   plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
              '$':'jquery',
              'jQuery':'jquery'

            }),
              new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()

               ],
  output: {path: __dirname, filename: "./public/bundle.js"},
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
      Main: "app/components/main.jsx",
      Nav: "app/components/nav.jsx",

      applicationStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss'
    },
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loaders:['react-hot','babel-loader','babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=react'],
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
};
```

Comment: What is your RHL version?

Comment: the latest one, ^3.0.0-beta.6